# Wash sale rule for me?

Tags: united-states, stocks, wash-sale

I am in US.

First of all I didn't knew wash sale applies for multiple accounts. That is completely my silliness.

- I purchased 100 shares of company X at $10 each in account 1 on January 1.
- I sold 30 of them in loss at $5 in February 15.
- Then I bought 5 shares of company X at $4 on February 20 in account 2.
- Then I sold the remaining 70 in account 1 for $3 in February 28.
- I am still holding position the 5 shares account2.

Does this trigger wash sale? How much and in how many shares/amount? Can I avoid it by end of 2021 as I can wait for position of account2 to be closed for several months.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's a wash sale, assuming these are taxable accounts. Separate accounts are irrelevant, even if they are held at different brokerages (you would be responsible for the basis adjustments in that case; otherwise your brokerage *should* handle it but you should confirm). Since you are still holding only 5 shares, and 30 days have passed since the last sale at a loss, those are the only shares you have to worry about.

You sold 30 shares at a loss of $5/share on February 15. Then you bought 5 shares at $4/share on February 20. Since that was within 30 days, your $4/share basis is adjusted up to $9/share. Therefore, your tax loss is deferred until you sell those remaining 5 shares, and don't repurchase for 30 days. You use the earliest sale according to [Fairmark](https://fairmark.com/investment-taxation/capital-gain/wash/wash-sale-matching-rules/), so that's why the adjustment is made with the February 15 sale rather than the February 28 sale.